# XML Conform Linebreak in PHP

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

I'm doing an XML generation where the main data is coming from xsl transformation (but that's not the problem, it's just the reason why I'm not using PHP DOM or SimpleXML).

Like this:

```
$xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . PHP_EOL;
$xml .= '<rootElement>';

foreach($xslRenderings as $rendering) {
    $xml .= $rendering;
}

$xml .= '</rootElement>';
```

The resulting XML validates against its XSD here http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html and here http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/.

But fails here: http://www.xmlforasp.net/schemavalidator.aspx,

```
Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the 
document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. 
Line 2, position 3.
```

If I do manually remove the line break produced by PHP_EOL and hit return, it validates.

I assume, that it's an error in the last schema validator. Or is PHP_EOL (or a manual break in PHP) something that is a problem for some validators? If yes, how to fix that?

I'm asking because the resulting XML will be send to a .NET Service and the last validator is built with NET.

**EDIT**

The XML looks like this, Scheme can be found here http://cb.heimat.de/interface/schema/interfaceformat.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://cb.heimat.de/interface/schema/interfaceformat.xsd">
<production foreignId="1327" id="0" cityId="6062" productionType="3" subCategoryId="7013" keywords="" productionStart="" productionEnd="" url=""><title languageId="1">
...
</production>
```

Comment: I checked http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html; it's trimming any whitespace, so I would think it is not helping in your case. http://xsdvalidation.utilities-online.info/ gives `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`. You need to post the bit of XML that gives the results you described above to get more help.

Comment: Except for the missing dataset tag, all is fine - it may the reformatting that SO does. If I may suggest, please place the generated XML file only in a ZIP archive, and upload it somewhere (you may find this [SO] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources) post helpful).

Comment: The dataset tag is missing for copy & paste reasons, it's there in the original.

Comment: That's what I thought. Again, if you can ZIP the XML as indicated above, particularly the one you used with the online validators and giving different results, I could help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to have a meeting with the .NET Provider tomorrow and report back. Unfortunately the XML contains sensible data, so i can't post it here.

Comment: Just remove the content of the root element, namespaces - as long as you can preserve the repro. Alternatively, you can email it to me separately, at the support address on my website, and you can have an NDA if you want. If it proves to be a bug, it is a rare find, hence my interest in it.

Answer (score 1):

You really have to look at the generated XML as a binary stream to understand what is going on. I'll try to explain what you should look at...

I'll show you a dump of an invalid XML (similar to yours) to help illustrate:

[image]

The first three bytes are Byte Order Mark and may be encountered with text files and streams (in this case UTF-8). Those kind of bytes would never cause a compliant XML parser to trip since are used as a hint for understanding the encoding scheme.

The next two bytes (0x0D0A) are new line on Windows platform. Those **should** cause any XML parser to fail well formed rules. According to the current XML 1.0 standard, white space is not allowed before the XML declaration.

On .NET you'll get an error such as the one you described. Java (xerces based) would say something more cryptic: `The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed. [2]`

Removing **any** white space before your first **`<`** should fix this error message. All you have to do is understand how that white space gets there...

From what you describe it looks as if the XML PI gets somehow dropped before using the XML.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no whitespace before the xml declaration. The error occurs because of first linebreak.

Comment: Sorry, but it can't be... I would be surprised at such a bug... Can you please post the **exact** string you're trying to validate (you can cut out the body content, leave the root)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time! I have added an example.